# Let $a, b, c, d$ be positive real numbers, such that $a+b+c+d=4 $ prove : $\frac{4}{abcd} \geq \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Let $a, b, c, d$ be positive real numbers, such that $a+b+c+d=4 $ prove : $\frac{4}{abcd} \geq \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}$

This is my attempt. I try to show that the last result is positive

$4 \geq a^2cd +b^2 da+c^2ba+d^2bc$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $(*) 16>=4a^2cd +4b^2da+4c^2ba+4d^2bc$

$(a+b+c+d) ^2 =16 \Rightarrow (**) 16 = a^2+b^2 +c^2 +d^2 +2 (ab+cd+ac+ad+bc+bd)$

($**and*$) $\Leftrightarrow$ $ a^2+b^2 +c^2 +d^2 +2(ab+cd+ac+ad+bc+bd)-4a^2cd +4b^2da+4c^2ba+4d^2bc>=0 $

$\Leftrightarrow$ $ (a-2acd)^2 +(b-bad) ^2 +(c-bac) ^2 +(d-bcd) ^2 +2(ab+cd+ac+ad+bc+bd) - 2(acd)^2 - 2 (abd) ^2 - 2(abc)^2 - 2(bcd)^2 \geq 0$

Comment: No, if a = b=c=d =1, the following is correct, look at my question now

Comment: @DavidDiaz Do you have a counterexample other than $a=b=c=d=1$?

Comment: If a =b=c=d=1, we find 4>=4, that is correct. So a=b =c =d =1 is not counterexample

Comment: if you have a=b=c=d, then the RHS becomes 4, and the LHS can become arbitrarily small, maybe the inequality is the other away around or for negative real numbers?

Comment: @person There is the constraint $a+b+c+d=4$. (This is why I recommend putting the *full question* in the post. It's easy to miss things when its crunched in the title.)

Comment: sorry didn't see that, my screen is small so it got cut out

Comment: Wait until Michael Rozenberg wakes up :) He solves ten problems of this kind before breakfast.

Comment: @Oldboy Someone might need to add the inequality tag though.

Comment: @halrankard2 Added inequality tag!

Comment: After multiplying by $abcd$ (as performed in the post) this gets (modulo variables renaming) the inequality
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184266